# Operator & not compatible with types bytes32 and int_const

Tags: solidity, truffle

i have the code below:

```
    uint256 lastBlockNumber = block.number - 1;
    bytes32 hashVal = bytes32(block.blockhash(lastBlockNumber));
    bytes5 _byteData = bytes5((hashVal & 0xffffffff) << 216);
```

the last line bytes5((hasVal & 0xffffffff) << 216); was working perfectly with solidity 0.4.18 but once i am trying it with 0.5.2 its not working i am getting the error below:

> Operator & not compatible with types bytes32 and int_const 4294967295

i am not able to resolve this, any idea on how to resolve it? thank you

Comment: Have you tried `uint256(hashVal)` instead?

Comment: @goodvibration i tried it but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

i have found the solution below and it worked

```
    uint256 lastBlockNumber = block.number - 1;
    bytes32 hashVal = bytes32(blockhash(lastBlockNumber));
    bytes5 _byteData = bytes5((hashVal & bytes32(0xffffffff)) << 216);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Conversions between bytesX and uintY of different size are now disallowed due to bytesX padding on the right and uintY padding on the left which may cause unexpected conversion results. The size must now be adjusted within the type before the conversion. For example, you can convert a bytes4 (4 bytes) to a uint64 (8 bytes) by first converting the bytes4 variable to bytes8 and then to uint64. You get the opposite padding when converting through uint32.

This is from the [docs breaking changes after 0.5.0 pragma version](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html)

Comment: Thank you i have fixed the issue, will post it below